# set attribute using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to set display to none of anchor tag using javascript.

i'm using below javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        setTimeout(function () {

            $("#SwitchToReadingMode-Small14").style.display = 'none';

        }, 1000);

    });

 </script>
```

but it gives me error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined.

PLease note that: anchor tag is not in my form. i'm finding that tag and id by pressing F12 button (inspect element). i'm using one embeded code url. on that url this anchor tag is exist

Answer (score 1):

`$("#SwitchToReadingMode-Small14")` returns a jQuery object so it does not have the `style` property. Instead you can use the [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method provided by jQuery to hide the element

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#SwitchToReadingMode-Small14").hide();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing a jQuery object, not a DOM node here. Use

```
$("#SwitchToReadingMode-Small14")[ 0 ].style.display = 'none';
```

or (better) just use jQuery

```
$("#SwitchToReadingMode-Small14").hide();
```

Comment: i try this. not giving any error. but also not worked. it is not hiding anchor element

Answer (score 1):

That's because here you use JQuery and not the javascript DOM object

replace:

```
 $("#SwitchToReadingMode-Small14").style.display = 'none';
```

by:

```
document.getElementById("SwitchToReadingMode-Small14").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: also try this code.it gives error uncaught type error cannot read property 'style' of null